# Change length of menu bar in ddslick

Tags: jquery, css

I can create a drop down menu with image using ddslick. But is it possible to change the length of the menu bar ? When it drop down to select can show longer bar, but after selected, the menu bar length only just fit the image chosen ?
I found the code here https://github.com/devluis/ddslick
but look like they dont define that option anywhere !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It is the width option. Sorry for bothering you.